# Are history of software, technical concepts or other not touchable computing-related things on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we want to have questions involving history of software? What about software development i.e. retro programming languages and compilers etc? Should we restrict any question types in this topic?

And what about general concepts, like multi-user environments, user privileges, event-driven applications, object-oriented programming, etc?

Also, how shall we handle questions about history of e.g. the internet?

Comment: I'm inclined to open things up as much as possible and let the community sort things out as we go.